# Possible to create a PDF that includes LO Writer's "Document Background" color?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, colors

LibreOffice Writer includes an "Export to PDF" option. When I use this, the PDF's background is always white. Yet in the LibreOffice Writer file I am exporting from, it has a dark-gray background. In LibreOffice Writer, I navigated to *Tools > Options > LibreOffice Appearance > General: Document background* and set it to the color dark-gray. I also set the Font Color to "gray 1" (a very light gray)

Is there any way to get these color changes to represent in the PDF that I create when using "Export to PDF"? I want to create a PDF that has a dark background and uses a white font for text.

Comment: You could change the *page's* background color (`Format`-->`Page...`-->`Background`) rather than the application's document background: however the chosen color won't extend outside the page margins AFAIK.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/468900/84724 ...